# webpack issue currently no loaders are configured to process this file in pdfjs-dist new URL("./build/pdf.worker.js", import.meta.url)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-4, pdfjs-dist

I have tried several versions of pdfjs-dist": "^3.5.141" to import the library in my project. but I am still getting the same error:

```
./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/webpack.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| if (typeof window !== "undefined" && "Worker" in window) {
|   pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new Worker(
>     new URL("./build/pdf.worker.js", import.meta.url)
|   );
| }
```

in the beginning of my project  i am importing the files as

```
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack'
import { getDocument, PDFWorker } from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

same is working in my React project 18.XX v

but i am facing issue in Next project.

I have tried:

loaders in next.config.js
still they are not working.

next.config.js file

```
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['pdfjs-dist'],{
   resolveSymlinks: false,
   debug: true,
});

module.exports = withPlugins([withImages],[withTM], {
  module: {
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
          source: "/colleges-campus-plments/test",
          destination: "/employer",
        },
      ];
    },

     rules: [


      {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|pdf)(\?.*)?$/i,
      include: /node_modules\/pdfjs-dist/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
          fallback: 'file-loader',
          publicPath: '/_next/static/',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        }
      }
    }
   
    //  {
    //    test: /\.pdf$/, 

    //     use: {
    //       loader: 'babel-loader'
    //     }
    //   },


      // {
      //   test: /\.pdf$/,
      //   use: {
      //     loader: 'worker-loader',
      //     options: {
      //       name: '[name].[ext]'
      //     }
      //   }
      // }
    ],


  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // This works, and returns appropriate Response headers:
        source: "/(.*).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|webp|jfif)",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Cache-Control",
            value:
              //"public, max-age=180, s-maxage=180, stale-while-revalidate=180",
              "public,max-age=31536000,immutable",
            //"public, max-age=9999999999, must-revalidate",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        // This doesn't work for 'Cache-Control' key (works for others though):
        source: "/_next/image(.*)",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Cache-Control",
            // Instead of this value:
            value:
              //"public, max-age=180, s-maxage=180, stale-while-revalidate=180",
              "public,max-age=31536000,immutable",
            // Cache-Control response header is `public, max-age=60` in production
            // and `public, max-age=0, must-revalidate` in development
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },

  images: {
    domains: ["logo.clearbit.com", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"],
  },
 


  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Add a new rule to handle fonts that come with pdfjs-dist
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|pdf)(\?.*)?$/i,
      include: /node_modules\/pdfjs-dist/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
          fallback: 'file-loader',
          publicPath: '/_next/static/',
          outputPath: 'static/',
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        }
      }
    });

    return config;`your text`
  },
```

file where I am using this is

just error is occuring during bundling of the package

Answer (score 0):

The error may have nothing to webpack loaders.

From the two article [MDN import.meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta) and [Javascript import.meta](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-import-meta/), the `import.meta` may only be used in es module context, webpack default output is not set as es module. You can enable [outputModule](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputmodule) to see if anything change.